# Select list in foreach not populating

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a select list using knockout databinding for the options list.  Nothing shows when the view loads, but there is data in the obervablearray DDABankNums the list is bound to.

Here is my select list-

```
                <select id="Select1" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 24px; width: 160px !important"
                    data-bind="value: DDABankNums().LoanNum, optionsText: DDABankNums().AccountName, optionsCaption: 'Select...', optionsValue: DDABankNums().LoanNum">
                </select>
```

viewmodel code-

```
 define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/CertificateDataService'],
function (logger, system, router, CertificateDataService) {
    var allCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);
    var myCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);
    var isSelected = ko.observable();
    var serverSelectedOptionID = ko.observable();
    var filter = ko.observable(0);
    var CertificateDetails = ko.observableArray([]);
    var DDABankNums = ko.observableArray([]);

    var CertificateDetailsToShow = ko.computed(function () {
        GetCertificateDetails();

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(CertificateDetails(), function (CertD) {
            return CertD.CertificateID == filter();
        });
    });

    var serverOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Certificate', OptionText: 'lwCertID' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Client Name', OptionText: 'clientName' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Client Number', OptionText: 'clientNumber' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Request Date', OptionText: 'requestDate' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Collateral Analyst', OptionText: 'userName' }
    ];

    var activate = function () {
        // go get local data, if we have it
        return SelectAllCerts(), SelectMyCerts(), CertificateDetailsToShow(), GetDDABankNums();

    };


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        ResetFilter: ResetFilter,
        filter: ko.observable(),
        allCertificates: allCertificates,
        myCertificates: myCertificates,
        CertificateDetails: CertificateDetails,
        CertificateDetailsToShow: CertificateDetailsToShow,
        DDABankNums: DDABankNums,
        title: 'Certificate Approvals',
        SelectMyCerts: SelectMyCerts,
        SelectAllCerts: SelectAllCerts,
        theOptionId: ko.observable(1),
        serverOptions: serverOptions,
        serverSelectedOptionID: serverSelectedOptionID,
        SortUpDownAllCerts: SortUpDownAllCerts,
        isSelected: isSelected,
        selectThing: function (row, event) {
            filter(row.lwCertID);
            isSelected(row.lwCertID);
        }

    };



    serverSelectedOptionID.subscribe(function () {
        var sortCriteriaID = serverSelectedOptionID();
        allCertificates.sort(function (a, b) {
            var fieldname = serverOptions[sortCriteriaID - 1].OptionText;

            if (a[fieldname] == b[fieldname]) {
                return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : a[fieldname] < b[fieldname] ? -1 : 0;
            }

            return a[fieldname] > b[fieldname] ? 1 : -1;

        });

    });

    return vm;

    function GetDDABankNums() {
        return CertificateDataService.getDDABankNums(DDABankNums);
    }

    function ResetFilter() {
        filter(0);
        isSelected(false);
    }

    function GetCertificateDetails() {
        return CertificateDataService.getCertDetails(CertificateDetails);
    }

    function SortUpDownAllCerts() {
        allCertificates.sort();
    }


    function SelectAllCerts() {
        return CertificateDataService.getallCertificates(allCertificates);
    }

    function SelectMyCerts() {
        return CertificateDataService.getMyCertificates(myCertificates);
    }


});
```

Why is the list not populating?

Answer (score 1):

In the data-bind attribute of your list, you are missing the "options" binding. You have optionsTest, optionsValue, etc. but the options (which you're missing) is what actually populates the select list with data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your knockout binding from

```
 var allCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);
```

into:

```
 var allCertificates = ko.observableArray();
```

The [ko.observableArray()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) itself an array no need to add *[ ]*

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I totally hosed this question.  I updated the code, it is the DDABankNums observablearray it is tied to.  Sorry for the confusion. Data still does not show up, and I did remove the [] as suggested.  Thanks.